# R ggplot contour plot does not cover entire plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to plot a scatter plot and add contour lines to it. I did get contour lines but it does not fill my entire data.

```
ggplot(training_validation, aes(x=training_mean, y=validation_mean, color = threshold)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "gold","gray79","midnightblue")) +
  theme( panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Mean Training AUC") +
  ylab("Mean Validation AUC")  + 
  stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..,alpha=..level..), geom='polygon',colour='black') +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="green",high="red") + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm,linetype=2,colour="red",se=F) +
  guides(alpha="none")
```

This is what I get - 
[image]

I want the contour lines to fill the entire plot. How can I do it?

Comment: Probably something like `scale_fill_gradient(low="green",high="red", limits=c(0,30))`.

Comment: please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @eipi10 it still gives me the same plot

Comment: Where do you want more lines? It looks like the `..level..` value beyond the last contour line would be very low already.